# Lambda in Java: Find repeated id and throw exception

Tags: java, spring, lambda, filter, stream

I want to check a list and throw exception if there is multiple id in the list using lambda expression:

```
final List<UUID> carUuidList = carRepository.getUuidList(); 

for (int i = 0; i < carUuidList.size(); i++) {
    final UUID carUuid = carUuidList.get(i);
    if(carUuidList.stream().filter(c -> c.equals(carUuid)).collect(Collectors.toList()) > 1){
        //throw exception
    }
}
```

But it does not work and I think there is a better way using `.orElseThrow(() -> ... ())`. So, how can I check the `carUuidList` and throw error if there is multiple uuid?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? You get wrong result?

Comment: @talex "Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'java.util.List<java.util.UUID>', 'int'"

Comment: ```carUuidList.stream().filter(c -> c.equals(carUuid)).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() > 1``` is probably what you want?

Comment: You're comparing list of UUID to int. I think, you should use `carUuidList.stream()...collect(...).size() > 1`

Comment: a `List` is not an `int` and thus can not be compared.  You collect your filtered list of UUID's to a `List` and then compare that to an `int`.  Basically you need to use `.size()` in your size comparison.

Comment: What about `.orElseThrow(()` part?

Comment: As an aside, you _might_ be able to detect duplicates by adding your `List` to an empty `Set` and then comparing the size of the `List` and the `Set`.  Of course that wont tell you which elements were duplicates.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking about `orElseThrow`?

Answer (score 1):

A java 9+ solution with a short-circuiting `HashSet<>()::add` instead of `new HashSet<>(list)` which iterates over the entire list:

```
List<UUID> carUuidList = carRepository.getUuidList(); 

carUuidList.stream()
           .dropWhile(new HashSet<>()::add)
           .findFirst()
           .ifPresent(dup -> {throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate found: " + dup);} );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but `if (carUuidList.size() != new HashSet<>(carUuidList).size())` is much more simpler and easier to understand what's going on there. I do not understand why Java brings new features with much more complex and longer solutions with the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you need a lambda? You can assume if there are all unique ids in the list, that a HashSet from this list will have the same size.

```
if (carUuidList.size() != new HashSet<>(carUuidList).size())
   //throw exception
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a `Set` based on the given `List` and then compare their sizes. If the `List` is larger than the `Set`, then there were duplicates. Otherwise there's not. Here's how it looks in practice.

```
final Set<UUID> uuidSet = new HashSet<>(carUuidList);
if (uuidSet.size() != carUuidList.size())
    throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate UUIDs found.");
```

This solution runs in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a second list, which only contains the unique uuids using streams like in this example:

```java
final List<UUID> distinctCarUuidList = carUuidList.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After that you can just compare the sizes of the 2 lists and throw an exception if the size is different:

```java
    if(distinctCarUuidList.size() != carUuidList.size()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

Comment: I think using a `Set` is somewhat more intuitive.  Of Course in your solution you might be able to use the `.equals` method as both objects are of type `List` rather than their respective sizes.

Comment: I think this is somewhat of personal preference. I think the most important is a good variable-naming. When using `.equals` there is a risk, if the two lists are not sorted the same way.

Comment: Yes, `Set` seems to be better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @csalmhof that is a risk yes.  Cant believe I forgot that! Nice to be reminded of the details ever now and then :)

Answer (score 0):

One else alternative solution using Stream API:

```
if (IntStream.rangeClosed(0, carUuidList.size()-1)
             .anyMatch(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, carUuidList.size()-1)
                                     .filter(j -> j != i)
                                     .anyMatch(j -> carUuidList.get(i).equals(carUuidList.get(j)))))
  throw new Exception("Duplicates found");
```